# Mongoose bind params to $where with js expression

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, where-clause

I am using Mongoose and I am trying to make this code work

```
var month = req.params.month;

Holiday.find({
    $where: function() {
        return this.date.getMonth() == month;
    }
}).lean().exec(function (err, docs) {
    return res.json(docs);
});
```

I need to access the `month` variable inside the function in the $where operator. How can I do this or can I modify this query to get all holidays saved in the database for the particular month?

Comment: Query looks fine. Please check that month query parameter is parsed as Integer (parseInt) before executing the equality check.

Comment: I have the error ReferenceError: month is not defined in the console

Comment: How does your route definition look like? Something like `app.get('/api/holidays/:month', function(req, res, next) {...})` ?

Comment: Yes, it looks like this

Comment: Can you verify (console.log) that month is properly set as req.params.month? Maybe a problem how your route is called and not a mongoose issue.

Comment: Any solution ? i have the same problem